# Updating application with new certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, app-store

To make a long story short: I have developed an application for a company and I was about to update when I discovered that in the member center area on the Apple website the Development Certificate was gone, as well as the devices and other stuff, so I made a new one and uploaded the device ID again.

So everything okay...I thought. I opened iTunes and downloaded the new provisioning profile and dragged it over to the organizer window. But it did not work. I got several different warning and errors saying the the keys, certificates etc did not match, so I Googled. I saw some posts that said: try making a new distrubution certificate...so I did, then xcode told me that I had to many certificates for that app so I exported the certificates by right clicking the selected certificates in the keychain and tapped export. I ended up with a Certificates.cer file. Then I deleted those certificates to make room for the new ones i downloaded from the member center portal.

SO now I do not know what I have done...I am afraid that I screwed something really up.

My question is: I really hope it is still possible to update the application already in appstore even though I have to recreate the certficates, provisioning profiles etc.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alway start from scratch, deleting all the provisioning profiles through your developer member page, recreating the profiles you need, importing them in Xcode and rebuilding the app with them. You cannot screw things that much, not being able to publish the app once again.

Clear all the contents of Xcode, and of your provisioning profiles page, and start over. Things will work. I've done this tens of times.

Comment: @Marzapower: Thank you for a quick reply and a happy message! Thought I had screwed it up big time. So I just download two new certificates, one for the developer and one for distribution, then I make new provisioning profiles right? And what about the app ID that will need to be recreated as well right?

Comment: You do not have to recreate the old app ID's. Actually I do not think you can. Just recreate the provisioning profiles and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Marzapower: Okay, but since I have revoked the original developer and distribution certificate I will have to get two new one first correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You have to "recreate" your configuration under the Provisioning Portal, then you reintegrate everything under Mac OS X and Xcode following the standard Apple guide.

Comment: @Marzapower: Thank you for your help! That was much appriciated. I will this. I accept your answer now, but I may ask one question in the comment field even though it is accepted if I a have question if you don't mind. Thank you, have a nice day!